# Removing scientific notation but with rounding in Matlab tick labels

Tags: matlab

I am plotting on a very small scale from a loop that generates a vector, `data`. Anyway, the `YTickLabel` is automatically in "6x10-3" format, for example.

```
data = [0.0004578945622489441 0.00154798436685536652442 0.005987463212456878422336324 0.003651558742652333624455];
plot(data)
```

I know I can use the following to have the full tick label displayed:

```
yt = get(gca,'YTick');
set(gca,'YTickLabel', sprintf('%.4f|',yt))
```

However, because these numbers are generated from my loop, they are very long (~20 digits) and so this displays them in full. I need to somehow round my ticks? (Without doing it manually using `YTickLabel = {'0.0001', '0.0002'};` ... etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', get(gca, 'YTick'))
```

In Matlab R2014b you could also use

```
ax = gca;
ax.YTickLabel = ax.YTick;
```

Either way, what this does is assign the YTick values to the YTickLabel. Somehow that prevents scientific notation.